# mpdf error - preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

i'm using MPDF to generate pdf files in codeigniter.

my controller function look like

```
   function save_pdf($std_id)
   {
     $data['section1_report']= $this->common_model->get_details('tbl_section1',array('id'=>$std_id));
     $html = $this->load->view('reports/section1',$data,true);
      // print_r($html);exit; 
     $this->load->library('pdf');
     $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
     $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
     $pdf->Output();
}
```

my `pdf` library is

```
 <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class pdf {    
      function pdf()
      {
         $CI = & get_instance();
         log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
      }

     function load($param=NULL)
     {
         include_once APPPATH.'/mpdf/mpdf.php';         
         if ($params == NULL)
         {
             $param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';         
         }         
       return new mPDF($param);
     }
  }
```

i want to generate pdf file from the view file `section1`. but when i call the controller function `save_pdf` , i got the errors as below

[image]

when i `print_r($html);exit;` , it displays all the contents from the view file.i used `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_replace` in `mpdf/includes/functions.php` but it's still showing error like this

[image]

i studied the `mpdf` documentation and it's working correctly in plain php. but i want to generate pdf file in `Codeigniter`.
how to solve such errors in `mpdf`? I would appreciate any help where i can generate `pdf file` using `mpdf` in `Codeigniter`. thank you.

Comment: I just googled "MPDF with Codeigniter", try e.g. https://davidsimpson.me/2013/05/19/using-mpdf-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try replacing lines 79 and 80 of `functions.php` with this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return code2utf($m[1],$lo); }, $str);
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return codeHex2utf($m[1],$lo);}, $str);
```

Source: https://github.com/carlholmberg/mpdf/issues/1

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me', "code2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
$str = preg_replace('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/me', "codeHex2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
// Remove above and add below code in includes/functions.php
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return code2utf($m[1],$lo); }, $str);
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return codeHex2utf($m[1],$lo);}, $str);

// Also comment below line in mpdf.php
$html = preg_replace('/\{DATE\s+(.*?)\}/e',"date('\\1')",$html );
```

Comment: this one works for me. I used the solution. it definitely remove the error, but make the pdf corrupted. but when I commented the line that you asked to commented, it works

Comment: Cheers with your changes!

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me', "code2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
$str = preg_replace('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/me', "codeHex2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
// Remove above and add below code in includes/functions.php
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return code2utf($m[1],$lo); }, $str);
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return codeHex2utf($m[1],$lo);}, $str);

// Also comment below line in mpdf.php
$html = preg_replace('/\{DATE\s+(.*?)\}/e',"date('\\1')",$html );
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced these lines:

```
   $str = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me', "code2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
   $str = preg_replace('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/me', "codeHex2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
```

with these line:

```
   $str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return code2utf($m[1],$lo); }, $str);
   $str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return codeHex2utf($m[1],$lo);}, $str);
```

and it worked correctly.